# Why doesn't my find function compare the nodes correctly?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I'm working on a concordance dictionary that reads a data file and records every unique word and the word's line number in a AVL tree. The problem is that my find method is not finding the Entry's within the tree so it adds every word instead of every unique word.

I'm also having trouble making my program keep a list of the line numbers within each entry. I'm using an entry class to keep the key(word) and the list of line numbers. Thank you for any help.

I'm writing in Python 2.7 and have included all my program so far.

My Main Program:

```
import string #NEW
from time import clock
import sys  #for BST recursion limit
from dictionary import Entry
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)#for BST

from avl import AVL

def main():
    """Calls on necessary functions to fill the dictionary, and process the keys"""
    start = clock() #times runtime
    stopWordDict = AVL()#Empty Dictionary
    stopWordDict = fillStopWordDict(stopWordDict)
    keyList = []

    wordConcordanceDict = AVL()#Empty Dictionary
    wordConcordanceDict = fillWordDict(stopWordDict,wordConcordanceDict, keyList)
    print str(wordConcordanceDict) #wordconcorddict made here.

    keyList.sort()
    print keyList
    writeWordConDict(wordConcordanceDict, keyList)

    end = clock() #gets runtime
    runTime = end - start
    print("Done. Runtime was:",runTime,"seconds.")

def fillStopWordDict(stopWordDict):
    """fills chain dict with all of the stop words"""
    fileNew=open('stop_words.txt', "r")

    for word in fileNew:
        word=word.lower().strip() #strip will strip \n from word
        if stopWordDict.find(word) == None:
            stopWordDict.add(word)
    fileNew.close()

    return stopWordDict

def fillWordDict(stopWordDict,wordConcordanceDict, keyList):
    """opens hw5data.txt and calls on processLine function"""
    lineCounter = 1
    fileNew=open('hw5data.txt', "r")
    for line in fileNew:
        processLine(lineCounter, line, stopWordDict,wordConcordanceDict, keyList)
        lineCounter+=1 #changes to next line of file
    fileNew.close()
    return wordConcordanceDict

def processLine(lineCounter, line, stopWordDict,wordConcordanceDict, keyList):
    """process each line into the wordConcordanceDict"""
    line=line.split() #splits line into list of words
    for word in line:
        word=word.lower().strip(string.punctuation)#strips punctuation
        if stopWordDict.find(word) == None:
            wordEntry = Entry(word, None)
            if wordConcordanceDict.find(wordEntry) == None:              
                lineList = wordEntry.value
                lineList.append(lineCounter)
                wordEntry.value = lineList
                wordConcordanceDict.add(wordEntry)
                keyList.append(word)
            else:
                wordEntry = wordConcordance.find(wordEntry)
                lineList = wordEntry.value
                lineList.append(lineCounter)
                wordEntry.value = lineList
                wordConcordanceDict.add(wordEntry)
     return wordConcordanceDict

 def writeWordConDict(wordConcordanceDict, keyList):
     """takes in wordConcordanceDict and list of its keys. Then prints the key value pairs to the screen"""
     fileNew=open("ProgProj5Concordance.txt", 'w')
#    listOfWords = wordConcordanceDict.inorder()
    for key in keyList:
         wordEntry = wordConcordanceDict.find(key) #makes the values into a string
         lineList = wordEntry.value
         line=str(key + ":" + lineList + "\n")
    fileNew.write(line)
    fileNew.close()

main()
```

MY ENTRY CLASS:
   """
    File: bst.py
    BST class for binary search trees.
    """

```
from queue import LinkedQueue
from binarytree import BinaryTree

class BST(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._tree = BinaryTree.THE_EMPTY_TREE
        self._size = 0


    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._tree)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.inorder())

    def find(self, target):
        """Returns data if target is found or None otherwise."""
        def findHelper(tree):
            if tree.isEmpty():
                return None
            elif target == tree.getRoot():
                return tree.getRoot()
            elif target < tree.getRoot():
                return findHelper(tree.getLeft())
            else:
                return findHelper(tree.getRight())

        return findHelper(self._tree)

    def add(self, newItem):
        """Adds newItem to the tree."""

        # Helper function to search for item's position 
        def addHelper(tree):
            currentItem = tree.getRoot()
            left = tree.getLeft()
            right = tree.getRight()

            # New item is less, go left until spot is found
            if newItem < currentItem:
                if left.isEmpty():
                    tree.setLeft(BinaryTree(newItem))
                else:
                    addHelper(left)                    

            # New item is greater or equal, 
            # go right until spot is found
            elif right.isEmpty():
                tree.setRight(BinaryTree(newItem))
            else:
                addHelper(right)
            # End of addHelper

        # Tree is empty, so new item goes at the root
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._tree = BinaryTree(newItem)

        # Otherwise, search for the item's spot
        else:
            addHelper(self._tree)
        self._size += 1

    def inorder(self):
        """Returns a list containing the results of
        an inorder traversal."""
        lyst = []
        self._tree.inorder(lyst)
        return lyst


    def preorder(self):
        """Returns a list containing the results of
        a preorder traversal."""
        # Exercise
        pass

    def postorder(self):
        """Returns a list containing the results of
        a postorder traversal."""
        # Exercise
        pass


    def levelorder(self):
        """Returns a list containing the results of
        a levelorder traversal."""
        # Exercise
        pass

    def remove(self, item):
        # Exercise
        pass

def main():
    tree = BST()
    print "Adding D B A C F E G"
    tree.add("D")
    tree.add("B")
    tree.add("A")
    tree.add("C")
    tree.add("F")
    tree.add("E")
    tree.add("G")

    print tree.find("A")
    print tree.find("Z")

    print "\nString:\n" + str(tree)

    print "Iterator (inorder traversal): "
    iterator = iter(tree)
    while True:
        try:
            print iterator.next(),
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            break

    # Use a for loop instead
    print "\nfor loop (inorder traversal): "
    for item in tree:
        print item,

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

AND FINALLY THE BINARY TREE AVL CLASS:

```
from binarytree import *

class BinaryTreeAVL(BinaryTree):
    def __init__(self, item, balance = 'EQ'):
        BinaryTree.__init__(self, item)
        self._balance = balance

    def getBalance(self):
        return self._balance

    def setBalance(self, newBalance):
        self._balance = newBalance

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the tree
        rotated 90 degrees to the left."""
        def strHelper(tree, level):
            result = ""
            if not tree.isEmpty():
                result += strHelper(tree.getRight(), level + 1)
                result += "| " * level
                result += str(tree.getRoot())+ " : " + tree.getBalance() + "\n"
                result += strHelper(tree.getLeft(), level + 1)
            return result
        return strHelper(self, 0)
```

Comment: Please produce a minimal example. We don't need the entire code. Focus on the line that goes wrong and try to remake the error with as little code as possible.